# IHostedService Error in ASP.NET Core app - why is the object already disposed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ihostedservice

I have created a Background Service in my Server Solution

```
public class PurgeService : IHostedService, IDisposable
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _provider;
    private Timer timer;
    public PurgeService(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        using (IServiceScope scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            _provider = scope.ServiceProvider;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        timer?.Dispose();
    }

    public Task Purge(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var dbcontext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDBContext>();
        var setting = dbcontext.AppSet.First();
        double deletetime = setting.PurgeTimer *(1);
        DateTime deletedate = DateTime.Now.AddHours(deletetime);
        string deleteSQL = $"DELETE FROM Notifications WHERE CreatedDate > {deletedate}"
    }
    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        timer = new Timer(x => Purge(_provider), null, TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

}
```

And added it to the Startup.cs

```
services.AddHostedService<PurgeService>();
```

My goal is to have a background service that checks every 10 seconds if there are notifications older than allowed and deletes them.

But when I run the app an error occurs

> "System.ObjectDisposedException: "Cannot access a disposed object."

How can I implement this correctly?

Comment: Thanks for recreating your question with the focus on ASP.NET Core rather than Blazor - much appreciated. The code is always very much appreciated. There is one detail you left out - which line of code is throwing the exception? And I have an unrelated comment - you should use parameterized queries rather than using string interpolation to form them. While in this case there's no SQL injection vulnerability, it's still creating a new query plan each time, it'd be more efficient if this was parameterized.

Comment: [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) shows changing the timer when the StopAsync method is called. Have you tried doing that?

Answer (score 2):

Your constructor seems to be establishing a scope, and immediately disposing the scope. Your provider is tied to that scope so gets nuked immediately in the constructor when Dispose() is called on the scope due to `using`.

Background services are usually singletons with a lifetime equivalent to the lifetime of the the application. It seems to me you should register your service as a singleton outside of the service class itself. Something like

```
public class PurgeService : IHostedService
{
   // no weird constructor taking in IServiceProvider
}
```

Also, using an IoC inside of a class is a bit of an antipattern. Inject a DB context factory instead of trying to resolve through a container inside your class.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was that the database table was empty, but the null exception threw a completely different exception.

Comment: The null exception threw a completely different exception? What does that mean? And you never even showed executing a query against the database in the code. You just showed construction of a webpage.